# Cannot draft a reply. Permission error

Tags: gmail-addons

I followed official guides https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/compose and https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/quickstart

Here is my appsscript.json:

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose"
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Gmail Add-on Quickstart",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/2x/bookmark_black_24dp.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "createReplyDraft"
    }],
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://mail.google.com/"
    ],
    "primaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "secondaryColor": "#4285F4"
  }
}
```

and Code.gs as:

```
  var composeAction = CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName('createReplyDraft');
  var composeButton = CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Compose Reply')
      .setComposeAction(composeAction, CardService.ComposedEmailType.REPLY_AS_DRAFT);

  // ...




  /**
   *  Creates a draft email (with an attachment and inline image)
   *  as a reply to an existing message.
   *  @param {Object} e data passed by the compose action.
   *  @return {ComposeActionResponse}
   */
  function createReplyDraft(e) {
    // Activate temporary Gmail add-on scopes, in this case to allow
    // a reply to be drafted.
    var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

    // Creates a draft reply.
    var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
    var draft = message.createDraftReply('',
        {
            htmlBody: "Kitten!"
        }
    );

    // Return a built draft response. This causes Gmail to present a
    // compose window to the user, pre-filled with the content specified
    // above.
    return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
        .setGmailDraft(draft).build();
  }
```

I want to open the "Reply" panel of my Gmail and paste some content into it.

It is giving Error following error: with the add-on.
Runtime error.
Access denied: : Cannot compose without user interaction.. [line: 27, function: createReplyDraft, file: Code]

I had already reinstalled module many times and also tried to give full scope permission of "https://mail.google.com/".

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it looks like you are trying to call your CreateReplyDraft function as soon as the add-on is loaded. Google does not allow that, the user would have to click a button in the UI to track creating a draft.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly** to your scope?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trigger compose action directly like this. You have to create a button widget which has linked [compose action](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button#setcomposeactionaction-composedemailtype)(your createReplyDraft function) with it. So when the user clicks on that button, compose action will be triggered.